# Are php sessions secure enough for a multi-tenant system

Tags: php, session

I am creating a multi-tenant system (first time). I am slightly worried about this system because all of the users details for the app will be kept in the same table's in the DB. When the user logs in I plan to set a `$_SESSION` variable that contains their `clientid` and use this to access all their information (all info in the DB will have `clientid` column).

I see this as the only solution to dealing with multi-tenant systems with PHP & MySQL. Is this secure enough? or should I opt for separate databases for each client. I am worried that if a client can change their `$_SESSION['clientid']` say from '12' to '45' that means they would then have access to someone else's data.

Is there a better method? or is the solutions the only way to deal with accessing data (PHP & MySQL) in a multi-tenant system?

Comment: Users can't change their own session data unless your code lets them do so.  If you're worried about them changing it, then don't give them a way to do so...

Comment: @Charles - Not entirely true, if he's doing what I think he's doing. He has to ensure that, if clients are being allowed to execute code, they can't manipulate the session files directly. Of course, that's more a server config issue, or perhaps a basedir issue.

Comment: @Charles the only time the '$_SESSION['clientid']' will be touched is for the user login and logout code.

Comment: As long as they're unable to execute arbitrary code allowing file manipulation on your server, sessions are entirely secure.

Comment: @Apropos "as long as users can't arbitrarily execute code".. if that were true you have a lot more to worry about than session security.

Comment: @MikeB haha yes. My first layer of defence for any code I write is ensuring users can't arbitrarily execute code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP keeps track of who is who by using sessions, which in turn use cookies to identify the *server* data.

The session cookie is something like

```
PHPSESSID=0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f... (32 hexits, usually)
```

The session data is stored on the server side, so a user will not be able to (easily*) change their `clientid` to someone else. I say easily, because it's possible for the user to try and [brute-force their PHPSESSID value](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Fixation) and gain access to another server session (but that should take a looong time).

It's also possible to use other tactics such as [XSS exploits](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Top_5#P2:_Cross-site_scripting) to discover other server sessions.

You can search StackOverflow for more information:

- [Session Fixation](https://stackoverflow.com/search-new?tab=votes&q=%5Bphp%5D%20session%20fixation)
- [Session Hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/search-new?tab=votes&q=%5Bphp%5D%20session%20hijacking)
- [Cross-Site Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/search-new?tab=votes&q=%5Bphp%5D%20XSS)

In order to be safe, make sure you don't output user input without prior sanitation (either by using HTMLPurifier or `htmlspecialchars()`) and call [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) whenever you login / logout or escalate the priviledges of a user.